# Invert 2 Strings in C

Tags: c, string

I have the following program that is supposed to invert 2 strings.
Ex:
Str1=a
Str2=b
Result: ba

However I have some Bug in the code that I can't find and it doesn't allow the program to invert the strings. Can someone take a look on this?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

/*
    Return the result of appending the characters in s2 to s1.
    Assumption: enough space has been allocated for s1 to store the extra
    characters.
*/
char* append (char s1[ ], char s2[ ]) {
    int s1len = strlen (s1);
    int s2len = strlen (s2);
    int k;
    for (k=0; k<s2len; k++) {
        s1[k+s1len] = s2[k];
    }
    s1[k+s1len]='\0';
    return s1;
}

int main ( ) {
    char str1[10];
    char str2[10];
    while (1) {
        printf ("str1 = ");
        if (!gets (str1)) {
            return 0;
        };
        printf ("str2 = ");
        if (!gets (str2)) {
            return 0;
        };
        printf ("The result of appending str2 to str1 is %s.\n", 
            append (str1, str2));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How is that code supposed to invert the strings? Even the function name says what it does - `append`.

Answer (score 2):

One problem you have is buffer overflow as your strings are *very* short; if the result string is longer than 10 bytes, your string arrays will overflow. Make them at least 80 bytes or something like that.

(Also, you shouldn't use `gets()`, since `gets()` doesn't check for string length, but as you're still learning, that is an issue for later).

Your append function appends s2 to s1, and you're calling `append (str1, str2)`, so you won't invert the strings. Try `append (str2, str1)` instead.

Comment: H, That worked, but isn't there any way to do this by only modify the function?

Comment: Sure. Check your loop and swap s1 and s2 as appropriate, then return s2 at the end.